# Big arrows between images

Tags: arrows

I am trying to put arrows between images. I did not want to put arrow images, I prefer LaTeX way solution. I used `pointer` from `wasysym` package. The result can be seen below. I know those arrows are considered as text, so they are tiny.

[image]

How can I put centered, big arrows between images?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `\vcenter` for vertical centering. It requires math mode. You could use font commands for scaling arrows or `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` of the graphicx package.

Define macros, so you could make adjustments easily.

Here's an example, using your pointer of wasysym:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\newcommand*{\vimage}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}}}}
\newcommand*{\vpointer}{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{2}{\Huge\pointer}}}}
\begin{document}
$\vimage{one}\vpointer
\vimage{two}\vpointer
\vimage{three}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you change those colors to say "yellow"? Cant get it to work

Comment: @eleijonmarck You could use one of the commands `\color` or `\textcolor`. Perhaps post a new question if you don't know these commands or how to use them here. You can link to here. Comments are just not for solutions or alternative way or follow-up questions.

Answer (score 7):

I used this [image](http://jimal-khalili.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/isaac_newton.jpg) and rename it as `newton.jpg`.

[image]

---

### Adjust the parameter until it suits your need.

```
\documentclass[final,cmyk,table]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsbsy}%bold math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}

% adjust until suit your need.
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}% you can change to a smaller. E.g., 5pt or less.
\arrayrulecolor{red}
\newenvironment{MyCrazyTable}[6][2cm]%
{%
    \newcolumntype{O}[1]%
    {%
        >{%
            \begin{minipage}[c][#1][c]%
            {%
                    ##1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth%
            }%
            \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
         }%
        c%
        <{%
                \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
                \end{minipage}%
         }%
    }%
    \newcolumntype{I}[1]%
    {%
        >{%
            \begin{minipage}[c][#1][c]%
            {%
                    ##1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth%
            }%
            \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
         }%
        c%
        <{%
                \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
                \end{minipage}%
         }%
    }%
    \begin{longtable}%
    {%
        |>{\centering}O{#2}%
        |>{\centering}I{#3}%
        |>{\centering}I{#4}%
        |>{\centering}I{#5}%
        |>{\centering}O{#6}%
        |%
    }%
    \hline\ignorespaces%
}%
{%
    \end{longtable}%
}

\newcommand{\myrow}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{newton.jpg}%
&%
\scalebox{1.1}{$\boldsymbol{\longrightarrow}$}%
&
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{newton.jpg}%
&%
\scalebox{1.1}{$\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}$}%
&
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{newton.jpg}%
\tabularnewline\hline%
}



\makeatletter
\newcommand\ratio[2]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr#1pt/#2\relax
}
\makeatother  


\begin{document}
\begin{MyCrazyTable}[5cm]%
    {\ratio{9}{33}}%adjust please
    {\ratio{3}{33}}%adjust please
    {\ratio{9}{33}}%adjust please
    {\ratio{3}{33}}%adjust please
    {\ratio{9}{33}}%adjust please
\myrow
\myrow
\end{MyCrazyTable}
\end{document}
```

---

You can show the frame by changing `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}` as shown below.
[image]

Comment: I suggest to comment out `[c][#1][c]` to make the height automatically get adjusted.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\def\Arrow{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\scalebox{4}{$\Rightarrow$}}}
\def\Image#1{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{#1}}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\Image{foo}\Arrow%
\Image{bar}\Arrow%
\Image{baz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: very good. they are not centered though.