# Labeled arrows between images

Tags: graphics, arrows

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/big-arrows-between-images) methods for adding arrows between images were shown. I'd like to add arrows between images with verbal above the arrows saying: "words words words", and below the arrows with sequences of mathematical symbols like $\gamma k_{aj}$

Comment: You can use `\xrightarrow` which comes with amsmath: `\xrightarrow[\gamma k_{aj}]{\text{if the $j$th protein is in the complex}}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the extensible arrows that come with mathtools.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx,mathtools}
\newcommand*{\vimage}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,angle=90]{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
$\vimage{example-image-a}\xRightarrow[\gamma k_{aj}]{\text{if the $j$th protein is in the complex}}
\vimage{example-image-b}\xRightarrow[\gamma k_{aj}]{\text{otherwise}}\vimage{example-image-c}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have fancier arrow, you could use Ti*k*Z.